# Java & MongoDB - Check if field name exists in nested arrays

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

Looking at this simplified example of a record in Mongo:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("573b30cb1d62485110330c35"),
  "changes": [
    {
      "after": {
        "comments": [
          {
            "user": {
              "idRef": "test1234",
              "name": "test user"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "after": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way, using Java's Mongo library, to iterate through each element in each nested array (changes -> after -> comments) and see if the user.idRef field exists?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following statement

```
db.collection.find({ "fieldToCheck" : { $exists : true, $ne : null } })
```

This will return a list of documents matching the criteria.

Comment: But I'm dealing with nested arrays, not just a simple hash field name.